# Using object item in an if statement after for

Tags: javascript, object

I am creating an object like this:

```
  markers[name] = {};
  markers[name].id = id;
  markers[name].lat = lati;
  markers[name].lng = longi;
  markers[name].state = state;
  markers[name].position = posi;
  markers[name].selected = false;
```

then i have a new function where i want to loop through the markers object and change the marker image .selected has been set to true.

Here is what i have tried:

```
function setMarkerImage() { 

        for (var key in markers) { 
           console.log("test 1: " + key + key.selected);
            if (key.selected === true)
          {
          console.log("test 2");        
             var newImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('img/presence/' + state + '_sel.png');
             var marker = $("#dispatcher").gmap3({action: 'get', name:'marker', tag: key})
               if (marker){
               marker.setIcon(newImage);
               }
          }
        } 
}
```

Problem is i am getting

```
test 1: Vinceundefined
```

in the console, i take it i cannot use key.selected like this?

Comment: It should be markers[key].selected .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`key` isn't an object, so it hasn't a `selected` key.  Try instead with

```
console.log("test 1: " + key + markers[key]["selected"]);
```